# (0, _.combineReducers) is not a function REDUX, REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

estoy desarrollando una app en react native (expo) y estoy utilizando redux y react navigation hasta ahora estoy haciendo la arquitectura del proyecto y me arroja este error

```
TypeError: (0, _.combineReducers) is not a function. (In '(0, _.combineReducers)({
    title: titleReducer,
    version: versionReducer
  })', '(0, _.combineReducers)' is undefined)
```

Esta es la parte donde dice que esta el error

```
// @packages
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

// @scripts
import { SET_APP_TITLE } from './actions';
import { config } from '_config';

/**
 * @returns {string}
 */
const titleReducer = (
    state = config.initialState.appInfo.title, 
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_APP_TITLE:
            return action.payload;
        case 'LOGOUT':
            return 'login';
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

/**
 * @returns {string}
 */
const versionReducer = (
    state = config.initialState.appInfo.version, 
    action
) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const appInfoReducer = combineReducers({
    title: titleReducer,
    version: versionReducer
});
```

mas adelante hay otra pagina donde hago el llamado de esta constante **appInfoReducer** y monto eso sobre otro reducer etc... si es necesario que envié mas info del código estoy pendiente.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay cosas que cambiaría.
Lo primero es que tienes una variable importada de actions en el switch (SET_APP_TITLE) el cual debería ser un string, pero el hecho de que se importe desde actions, me llama la atención.
Lo siguiente es que para almacenar la información para ese mismo caso, el return del switch debería ser así:

```
const { SET_APP_TITLE, LOGOUT } from './actions/types'; //Donde deberías tener un export de cada variable.
//Ej de /types: export const SET_APP_TITLE = 'set_app_title'; y todos los que usarás en tu app
//Deberías tener un initial state como este
const INITIAL_STATE = { title: 'Un titulo', versión: 1, actived: false };

const infoReducer = ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_APP_TITLE:
            return { ...state, title: action.payload }; //debes devolver siempre el state original más el cambio que quieres hacer.
        case LOGOUT:
            return { ...state, ...INITIAL_STATE }; //setear valores default
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Recomiendo un reducer por archivo, exportas cada uno y haz el combine reducer en el index de la carpeta reducer. Los reducer debes usarlos por segmento y no por función, o sea, un reducer para configuración inicial, y quedaría por ej: uno para configuración general, compras, otro para usuario, etc. los que necesites.

Entonces si es así agregamos al final (en /reducers/infoReducer.js) el
`export default infoReducer;`

El combineReducer quedaría así (/reducers/index.js):

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import infoReducer from './infoReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    info: infoReducer,
});
```

Luego en tu app.js o index.js como sea el caso tendras algo como esto

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './src/reducers';
import Router from './src/router'; //Donde tengas configurado tu react navigation

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

export default function(){
return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router/>
            <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor={COLOR.darkBlue}/>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```